# Sqlite database file caching issue

Tags: sqlite

I have demo.db3 file at 2 places. One in C drive & another in D drive. I used SQLite Expert to modify file on D drive. I deleted few tables & added rows.
Then I deleted file from C drive & copy pasted D drive file to C drive.
Now again if I open the C drive file in SQLite Expert then it is still showing me older database structure with no rows.
I used Winmerge tool to compare both the files & found no difference.
When I pasted D drive file to C drive location with a different name then it started showing me the new tables & rows in tables.
Then I deleted the older file and renamed new files with older name. Again I went to open the db3 file and now it shows me 2 files present in the same location. I am able to open both the files. File with older name does not show me new tables & rows but database with new files name does show.

I used few other tools (SQLStudio, SQL Administrator) to open the files but same issue.
Seems like the sqlite files are either cached in the application I am using to open or within the same file it is maintaining changes done in the tables.
Another strange thing is that though I delete/add tables to the database it does not change the Date Modified of the db3 file.

I am confused with this behavior. Please help me to understand the issue.

Comment: Open a command prompt. What is the output of `dir c:\demo*` and `dir d:\demo*`?

Comment: Through Command Prompt it is showing me only 1 files. However in the open dialog box it was still showing me 3 files. So I pressed shift & right clicked withing same dialog box & selected "Open Command Prompt here". Here when I used command DIR then it shown me all three files with different size & timestamp.
http://s27.postimg.org/pxfk2et43/1file.png
http://s27.postimg.org/vzn6swhk3/3files.png

Comment: Please note that the command prompt supports copy+paste. There is no D: in these pictures, and your refusal to show directoy and file names makes it hard to follow which file is which.